# React - changing state not updating elements rendered from variable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have stored a component in a variable `const span = <span>{this.state.text}</span>`. Now when I render this element and update the `text` within the state. The element is not re-rendered.

So this is my code

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'hey'
  }
  span = <span>{this.state.text}</span>

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.span}
        <div>State: {this.state.text}</div>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({text: 'hello'})}}>Update</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

So even after updating the state, the span has the initial value of the state. Is there any way to make this dynamic? I'm a newbie here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your code `span` is an instance property of `App` that once set will remain the same through out the lifecycle of your component unless set again manually. You would have to include that `span` html creation inside the `render` like so :-

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'hey'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         <span>{this.state.text}</span>
        <div>State: {this.state.text}</div>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({text: 'hello'})}}>Update</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

This is valid as well :-

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'hey'
  }
  span = <span>{this.state.text}</span>
  render() {
    this.span = <span>{this.state.text}</span>
    return (
      <div>
        {this.span}
        <div>State: {this.state.text}</div>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({text: 'hello'})}}>Update</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The below with having another function like `renderSpan` is valid as well :-

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'hey'
  }
  renderSpan = function(){
    return <span>{this.state.text}</span>
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.renderSpan()}
        <div>State: {this.state.text}</div>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({text: 'hello'})}}>Update</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

The below is achieved using the `shouldComponentUpdate` lifecycle method :-

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'hey'
  }
  span = <span>{this.state.text}</span>

  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps,nextState){
     this.span = <span>{nextState.text}</span>
     return true;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.span}
        <div>State: {this.state.text}</div>
        <button onClick={()=>this.setState({text:'hello'})}>Update</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

**There are just too many ways**. It's good to know why all of them work. Knowing their working means to understand both **JavaScript** (Here specifically **ES6 Class**) and **React** (Here specifically **Class Components)**.

Comment: Thank you..! I ended up using your function `renderspan()`. Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

`span` variable is not in state so it can't react to change. Try this

```
class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    text: 'hey'
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span>{this.state.text}</span>
        <div>State: {this.state.text}</div>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({text: 'hello'})}}>Update</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

or make new component and pass text as prop:

```
const SpanComponent = ({txt}) => {
   return <span>{txt}</span>
}
```

and then use it in your component

```
     <div>
        <SpanComponent txt={this.state.txt} />
        <div>State: {this.state.text}</div>
        <button onClick={()=>{this.setState({text: 'hello'})}}>Update</button>
      </div>
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/question-forked-noyir?file=/index.js

Comment: Check out line 9. Var `span` is not in state, `text` is.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/question-forked-noyir?file=/index.js

Answer (score 0):

You should read into React hooks, and for this case useState.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = useState();

  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div>State: {text}</div>
        <button onClick={() => setText("hello")}>Update</button>
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/falling-field-gyft1?file=/src/App.js